# Embedding of a Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ in its associated universal enveloping algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm reading Wiebel's Book *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*, and in the chapter *Lie Algebra Homology and Cohomology* under **Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt** theorem there is a Corollary which states without proof that

> The map $i : \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow U_{\mathfrak{g}}$ is an injection, so we may identify $\mathfrak{g}$ with $i(\mathfrak{g})$.

I presume that this may be without proof in there because consists a straightforward consequence of the aforementioned theorem, though I don't see why. There might be an easy explanation but I can't "see" it, so can you please help me out?

Also, any kind of reference instead is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBW tells you that for an ordered basis $\{e_\alpha\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, the set $\{e_I\}$ where $I$ runs through increasing sequences forms a basis of $U\mathfrak{g}$. In particular, all the $e_I$ are linearly independent. But
\begin{align*}
i : \mathfrak{g}&\to U\mathfrak{g}\\
e_\alpha&\mapsto e_{(\alpha)}.
\end{align*}
 Thus, $g = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha e_\alpha\in\ker i$ implies
$$
0 = i(g) = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha i(e_\alpha) = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha e_{(\alpha)},
$$
so $a_\alpha = 0$ for all $\alpha$, meaning $g = 0$ and $i$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so if I understand correctly the notation, by $e_{(a)}$ you denote just the image of a basis element of $\mathfrak{g}$ in the universal enveloping algebra, which is *exactly* the same element as in the Lie algebra we started with in the first place, but this time we looked at it as an element of $U_{\mathfrak{g}}$, and then because of the linear independency in $\mathfrak{g}$ we have zero coefficients in the latter as well, correct?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris I'm noting that the given basis element $e_\alpha\in\mathfrak{g}$ maps to one of the elements of the basis described by PBW. The image $i(e_\alpha)$ of the basis element $e_\alpha$ inside $U\mathfrak{g}$ isn't *exactly* the same element as the element $e_\alpha$, since they live in two different places, but knowing that $i$ is an injection lets you identify them safely.

Comment: In the above argument, we're using linear independence of the $e_{(\alpha)}$ inside $U\mathfrak{g}$ to deduce that the coefficients $a_\alpha$ are all $0$: we wrote $i(g) = 0\in U\mathfrak{g}$ as a linear combination of basis elements, so all coefficients must be $0$. Thus, since $g = \sum a_\alpha e_\alpha$, $g$ is $0$ as well.

Comment: The notation $e_I$ is explained on page 225 in Weibel, and $e_{(\alpha)}$ is a special case of this notation.

Comment: I put *exactly* like this to point out what you wrote out to be honest. They are not the same elements indeed, but due to the PBW theorem as you pointed out we can identify them safely though. That was quite helpful (although it seems quite easy in retrospect, as I suspected :)). Thank you again for your time.